# How can I get the custom object Tooling API Id?

Tags: custom-object, metadata, tooling-api

I want to get the custom object id using the custom object's API name.
Please tell me the way how to get id.

[image]

````
req.setEndpoint(domainUrl+'/services/data/v46.0/tooling/query?q='+
                        'SELECT+Layout.Name'
                        +'+FROM+ProfileLayout'
                        +'+WHERE+ProfileId='+'\''+profileId+'\''
                        +'+AND+TableEnumOrId='+'\''+aaa+'\'');
    ```
````

Comment: Why do you want the SObjectType Id?  What's the use case?

Comment: @BrianMiller Hi. In the case of a standard object, set the API name to 'TableEnumOrId'.For custom objects, I must set SObjectType instead of API name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it from the Tooling API itself. The Tooling API field you want is [`EntityDefinition.DurableId`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_entitydefinition.htm):

```
SELECT DurableId FROM EntityDefinition WHERE QualifiedApiName = 'Full_Name_of_Field__c'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!! It worked!!

Comment: This works but I think it should say `QualifiedApiName = 'Full_Name_of_Object__c'`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you meant by getting Id from object name.

Here is small notes on Ids and object API names.

You can get object API name by using Id. You can say `myId.getSobjectType()`. If you want to know all the objects' Ids then use SOQL `[SELECT Id FROM ObjectName]`.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness. But what I want to get is not the record's ID but the custom object's ID. When you open the object manager page, an ID that is not a record ID is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

S Kawasaki,

You can queried for you custom object using SOQL:

```
List<MyCustomObject__c> customObjs = [SELECT Id, Name, CustomField__c FROM MyCustomObject__c];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your kindness. But what I want to get is not the record's ID but the custom object's ID. When you open the object manager page, an ID that is not a record ID is displayed.