# Can not create Trigger for Custom Object with Tooling Api

Tags: trigger, tooling-api

I need to write logic for creating triggers for *Standard and Custom Objects*.
*It works for Standard Objects.*
**However when I try to create trigger for Custom Object with Tooling Api I get following error :**

> |[{"message":"Invalid object or access for 01I5g0000020tKR on field [TableEnumOrId]","errorCode":"INVALID_ARGUMENT_TYPE","fields":[]}]

Based on [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/270744/how-can-i-get-the-custom-object-tooling-api-id) and [this one](https://andyinthecloud.com/2014/01/05/querying-custom-object-and-field-ids-via-tooling-api/) I figured out next code

Here is my code for building request body (Custom Object Api name = 'My_Custom_Object__c'  :

```
 Http h = new Http();
HttpRequest hr = new HttpRequest();
hr.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+ UserInfo.getSessionId());   
hr.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() +'/services/data/v38.0/tooling/query?q=select+id,+DurableId +from+EntityDefinition +where+DeveloperName +=+\'My_Custom_Object__c\' );   
hr.setMethod(method);
HttpResponse r = h.send(hr);            
String res = r.getBody(); 
 String DurableId = res.substringBetween('"DurableId ":"', '}}]}');
String json = '{"Name" : "Tooling'+objName.capitalize()+
                'Trigger", "TableEnumOrId" : "' +DurableId  +
                '", "Body" : "trigger Tooling' +objName.capitalize()+
                'Trigger on '+objName.capitalize()+' (after insert, before update) {'+
                'if(Trigger.isInsert){'+
                    'String objType = String.valueOf(Trigger.New.getSObjectType());'+
                    'ZC_P2.HelperApexTriggerInsert.TriggerInsert(objType);'+
                '}'+
                'if(Trigger.isUpdate){'+
                    'ZC_P2.HelperApexTriggerInsert.TriggerUpdate(Trigger.new, Trigger.old);'+
                '}'+
                +'}"}';
```

Have anyone had something similar before  ??

Any help will be appreciated

thank you

Comment: Sorry, I can't answer this, but just for my curiosity: why are you creating a trigger this way?

Comment: @SanderdeJong this logic will be in managad package , So a user will have possibility to dynamically create Triggers for his Custom Objects with logic for the Integration which is in My managed package.